# tflearn linear regression ValueError : Cannot feed value of shape

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow, linear-regression, tflearn

I have the following `data` variable...

```
        A   B   C   D
    0  75  38  81  58
    1  36  92  80  79
    2  22  40  19  3
       ...    ...
```

...which I generated using the following...

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

I then split the data...

```
X = data.drop(['A'], axis=1).values
y = data['A'].values
```

...then I created a linear regression model with tflearn...

```
input_ = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None])
linear = tflearn.single_unit(input_)
regression = tflearn.regression(
    linear, 
    optimizer='sgd', 
    loss='mean_square', 
    metric='R2', 
    learning_rate=0.01
)

# Define model.
model = tflearn.DNN(regression)
model.fit(X, y, n_epoch=100, show_metric=True, snapshot_epoch=False)
```

I created the model based on a tutorial which I followed, however, I get the following error...

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 3) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?,)'

I tried changing the shape of `input_data` to fix this. I tried...

```
input_ = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 3])
```

...which gave me yet another error...

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64,) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(3,)'

I am not sure what shape they are asking for. I tried feeding the model in batches but I still got errors. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to take the transpose of the input data `X = data.drop(['A'], axis=1).T.values`, which has the right dimensions

Comment: @economy I did, still getting the same sort of `shape` errors